# Ghostscript - how to print labels on stickers not A4?

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, ghostscript

I have Dymo labelwriter printer: 
[image]

Which is used to print labels in sticker model 11356 (40mm, 80mm)

[image]

In Ghostscript which settings can be adjusted to tell it's not A4 nor A5, B5, EnvC5, but it has to be 40mm, 80mm? I tried following parameters, but it's not printing to 1 sticker, instead it keeps pushing out 20 stickers and printing in wrong label locations.

```
MediaSize A4
MediaSize A5
MediaSize B5
MediaSize EnvC5
MediaSize EnvDL
MediaSize EnvISOB5
MediaSize Postcard
MediaSize DoublePostcard
```

Therefore, I also have the PDF file itself made into 40mm by 80mm. But it keeps failing to print on 1 label/sticker.

How do I tell Ghostscript just to print the PDF with its exact default size. Without Ghostscript when I print the PDF it works perfectly but the moment I use Ghostscript it's doing abnormal paper settings and printing abnormally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not said how you are using `Ghostscript`. Which device are you using `CUPS`, `mswinpr2`, something else ?

All the `Ghostscript` devices will honour the media request from `PostScript` or `PDF`, and this will **override** any command line switch, unless you also set `-dFIXEDMEDIA`.

You haven't quoted an exact command line; but the `MediaSize` switch is deprecated and should not be used.

I'm going to guess that you are using `mswinpr2`, in which case `Ghostscript` will be using the **default** Media Size configured in the printer. I that's not correct, you need to alter it.

Comment: Sir, i am using 1) ` GSBatchPrint 32Bit (includes GS 9.15)

 ` http://www.lvbprint.de/html/gsbatchprint1.html 2) it has gswin32.exe, which read ini file

Comment: Sir, as you said its `mswinpr2` which should use the default media size. but its not doing that. When i print PDF directly without Ghostscript then label printing works. But when i use the Ghostscript then its printing and ejecting 20 labels instead of printing to 1 single sticker.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25627080/ - This is the INI file used by gsbatchprint.exe (mswinpr2)

Comment: You aren't using Ghostscript, you are using a hacked and illegal (its not complying with the AGPL) version of Ghostscript. In particular its using a modified version of the mswinpr2 device. Clearly I can't help you with that, you will have to contact the authors of the software.

Comment: OK - i am writing email to the author and point him to this comment and answer so that he can get the overview too. He clearly mentioned its Ghostscript in his doc. So there must a .ini file settings. Never mind thank you. its now very clear.